# Python list alignment

Tags: python, for-loop

I have an assignment I am trying to complete.

I have 100 random int. From those 100 I have to create a 10x10 table. DONE..
within that table I have to align my values to the right side of the each column. That is the part I'm missing.

Below is the code for that:

```
    print(num, end=("  " if counter < 10 else "\n"))
```

Comment: Everyone knows that 95% of the code takes 95% of the effort/time. Then the final 5% takes *another* 95% of the effort/time :-) The thing you need to search for is `fstrings` (preferred) or the `format` method of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just format the number before printing it.

```
print(f"{num:>5}", end=("  " if counter < 10 else "\n"))
```

Alternatively, if you wanna cast the numbers to string you can use the rjust method of string.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but you can also use:

```
import random

rl = random.sample(range(100, 999), 100)
max_n = 10
for n, x in enumerate(rl, 1):
  print(x, end=("\n" if n % max_n == 0 else "  "))
```

---

```
440  688  758  837  279  736  510  706  392  631
588  511  610  792  535  526  335  842  247  124
552  329  245  689  832  407  919  302  592  385
542  890  406  898  189  116  495  764  664  471
851  728  292  314  839  503  691  355  350  213
661  489  800  649  521  958  123  205  983  219
321  633  120  388  632  187  158  576  294  835
673  470  699  908  456  270  220  878  376  884
816  525  147  104  602  637  249  763  494  127
981  524  262  915  267  873  886  397  922  932
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to do it. I hope I have made it clear.

```
import random
# Generate 100 random numbers in range 1 to 1000.
random_numbers = list(map(lambda x:random.randrange(1,1000), range(100)))
# Create an empty string to store the pretty string.
pretty_txt = ''

# Loop through random_numbers and use an enumerate to get iteration count.
for index, i in enumerate(random_numbers):
    # Add the current number into the string with a space.
    pretty_txt += str(i) + ' '
    # Add a newline every ten numbers. 
    # If you don't add index != 0 it will put a space in first iteration
    if index % 9 == 0 and index != 0:
        pretty_txt += '\n'

print(pretty_txt)
```

The output is:

```
796 477 578 458 284 287 43 535 514 504 
91 411 288 980 85 233 394 313 263 
135 770 793 394 362 433 370 725 472 
981 932 398 275 626 631 817 82 551 
775 211 755 202 81 750 695 402 809 
477 925 347 31 313 514 363 115 144 
341 684 662 522 236 219 142 114 621 
940 241 110 851 997 699 685 434 813 
983 710 124 443 569 613 456 232 80 
927 445 179 49 871 821 428 750 792 
527 799 878 731 221 780 16 779 333
```